# Why am i getting this error? need help please

Tags: python

I am getting this error.. code not submitting 
need help thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Share code, never picture please, and explain what you did, and provide a title that has a sense please

Comment: ... we can't even see the error, putting the fact that it's an image aside. That's the start of the traceback, the error comes at the end but it's cut off

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error is in finding the midpoint.

In python, if we use `len(lst)/2` it will return float value.

The Index of list cannot be a floating point value.

Change your line to:

```
midpoint = len(lst)//2
```

This will return an Integer value as output.